# Use select to create new column names - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select, alter

I am trying to figure out how to write one statement where I can grab a value with a select statement and use that value to create a new column. for example:

```
SELECT CONCAT( SUBSTRING(latestfile.short_filename,6,5),'_m') 
FROM  latestfile 
LIMIT 9,1
```

**this gets me the value I want**

then almost "add" it to this type of statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `latestfile` 
ADD `newvaluefromaboveselectstatement` VARCHAR( 35 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

My select statement above is specifically pulling position "9,1" I really want to do this for "8,1" then 7,1, then 6,1 etc.

Is this possible?